# How to change font style to "Arial" for tab_model() output

Tags: css, r

I am trying to change the font style of my tab_model() table to Arial but am still failing after a few hours of trying.

Here is an example data:

`mod <- lm(log10(Spike) ~ Group + Vaccine + Gender + Smoking + Ethnicity + Age + imp_days1 + V1POS, data = newdata2)`

The following is how I generate the table:

```
tab_model(mod, auto.label = FALSE, string.p = "p-value", string.pred = "Variable",
      show.intercept = FALSE,  
      pred.labels = c("Infliximab","Infliximab+Thiopurine", "Thiopurine", "Tofacitinib", "Ustekinumab", 
                      "Vedolizumab", "Vaccine[mRNA]", "Sex","Smoking","Ethnicity[White]",
                      "Age","Days post vaccine", "Prior infection"))
```

I have tried adding `CSS = list(css.footnote = "Arial")` or `CSS = list(css.footnote = "Arial;")`, but both didn't work.

The table looks like this: [the tab_model generated HTML table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdniG.png)

And I hope the font can look like this: [example found on the internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqc7u.png)

Thank you for reading my question, any advice would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CSS` argument inside `sjPlot::tab_model`.

```r
library(sjPlot)

# Sample fit
fit <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)

# Table
tab_model(fit, CSS = list(css.table = '+font-family: Arial;'))
```

[image]

See also `?sjPlot::tab_model` for more details on how to use the `CSS` argument.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I need. Thank you for helping and for the additional information provided!

Comment: Great & you're very welcome @drwtlin. If this answers your question you may consider closing the post by setting the green checkmark next to the answer.